# React Native Navigation navigate not firing from useEffect

Tags: react-native, use-effect, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to write a React Native Functional Component that simply checks some values within a Redux state, and depending on that result immediately re-routes the user to the correct screen.

If I send the wrong routeName to the navigate function, it will throw an error stating that it couldn't find the route. But when I pass a routename that exists, then it will just do nothing.

I can verify 100% that navigation and wizard have the proper data for this to work. Any ideas what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const SetupLoader = ( props:any ) => {
    const { navigation, wizard } = props;

    let setupRoute = '';

    useEffect(() => {
        // HANDLE CASE OF MID-REGISTRATION
        if (!wizard.step1) {
            setupRoute = 'Step1';
        }
        if (!wizard.step2) {
            setupRoute = 'Step2';
        }
        else {
            setupRoute = 'Dashboard';
        }
        navigation.navigate(setupRoute);
    },[]);

    return (
        <View></View>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = ( state:any ) => ({
    wizard: state.wizard
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SetupLoader);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks in part to Wen, I was able to get it to work. I tied the redirect route name into a state variable. useEffect then updates that variable and on the second pass through useEffect, navigation is called and the screen re-routes correctly.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const SetupLoader = (props: any) => {
    const { navigation, wizard } = props;

    const [route, setRoute] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (route === '') {
            let setupRoute = '';
            if (!wizard.step1) {
                setupRoute = 'Step1';
            } 
            else if (!wizard.step2) {
                setupRoute = 'Step2';
            } 
            else {
                setupRoute = 'Dashboard';
            }
            setRoute(setupRoute);
        } else {
            navigation.replace(route);
        }
    }, [ route ]);
        
    return (
        <View></View>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    wizard: state.wizard
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SetupLoader);
```

Answer (score 1):

couple of things to make sure:

1. make sure your SetupLoader component is mounted.
2. you need to listen in on the changes for the wizard state variable.

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
> // HANDLE CASE OF MID-REGISTRATION
>  if (!wizard.step1) {
>    setupRoute = 'Step1';
>  }
>  if (!wizard.step2) {
>    setupRoute = 'Step2';
>  }
>  else {
>    setupRoute = 'Dashboard';
>  }
>  navigation.navigate(setupRoute);
> },[wizard]);
> ```